# Time out period for a logic app sitting in multi-tenant environment?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

What is total time out period for a logic app sitting in multi-tenant environment?

As I found the information from the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits, it gives time out period for each inbound request and responses only.

Here I would like to understand what is the total time out period for entire flow to complete ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the timeout limit just applies only to some actions(such as HTTP action). For the whole logic app flow, it doesn't exist a limit for timeout. For example, in logic app you can use "[Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-delay#add-the-delay-action)" action to delay arbitrary time.

[image]

The whole flow will wait the delay action and then continue execute.

By the way, the logic app is not billed by the hour but billed by running actions account,  so it will cost more if run for longer.